# Refresh page questions/tagged/ on tab newest after ctrl+click the tab featured brings me to featured tab

Tags: bug

I usually have this kind of link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag1+or+tag2+or+...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala+or+apache-spark) opened and displaying newest questions I could potentially answer.

From time to time I open in a new browser tab the featured questions using ctrl+click on the "featured" tab (next to the "newest" tab).

Then at some point I'll switch back to the previous browser tab (which displays the "newest" tab) waiting for a new question to pop-up.

At some point, I get the notification that a new question is available (message "1 question with new activity" at the top) and I click it. This has for effect to add the question at the top of the stack of questions.

But then, if I hit refresh (in order to update view count, answers, ...) instead of refreshing on tab "newest", it refreshes on tab "featured".

Hope I'm clear enough. Not much of an issue, but might be worth having a look.

Using Chrome, same behavior with Windows/Linux.